# Mysql View of last version of some strings

Tags: mysql, sql, view

In my database, I have a table that contains all the versions of a certain translated strings. I want to create a view that returns a table with all the latest versions of each string.

I've come up with the following solution.

```
Table Strings
idString, Date, String, Chapter
```

These are the attributes of the table

```
View StringOrdered
Create  View StringOrdered(idString, Date, String, Chapter) AS
SELECT * FROM Strings ORDER BY Date DESC
```

This is the supporting view.

```
View LastVersion
CREATE VIEW LastVersion (idString, Date, String, Chapter) AS
SELECT * FROM StringOrdered GROUP BY Chapter
```

Is there a way to obtain it without the supporting view?

Comment: Is idString unique in the entire Strings table, or a combined key with date? i.e. Could you have two dates for the same idString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are depending on the `group by` taking the last version of something, based on the ordering of the data.  Although this might work in practice, MySQL documentation specifically says this is not supported.  Instead, try something like:

```
create view LastVersion as
    select s.*
    from strings s
    where s.chapter = (select max(chapter)
                       from strings s2
                       where s.String = s2.String
                      )
```

I am assuming that you are looking for the latest chapter for `String`.  If you are looking for the latest chapter for `StringId`, then change the `where` statement accordingly.

Note that MySQL does not support subqueries in the `from` clause of a view.  The quote is quite clear ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html)):

> The SELECT statement cannot contain a subquery in the FROM clause.

It does support subqueries in other clauses.